# Apache HttpClient 4.4 in tomcat7 with Spring

Tags: tomcat7, apache-httpclient-4.x

I came up with a project design that includes now some crawling using apache http client. All the project is deployed in tomcat7 as webapp and is wired with spring. The behavior of the http client is quite different inside it however. I am trying to download a file and it freezes somewhere during consuming the content - something that succeeds outside tomcat. Yes, I set all the timeouts for the request. Yes, I read this [reason not to use http client in containers](http://bit.ly/1GWqFWc) , but I am curious if I still can save the arrangement of my project ?

Comment: All said in the post you are referring to allies to EJB containers only. HttpClient with a connection pool should be perfectly fine in web containers. Run HttpClient with wire / context logging to find out why it behaves differently inside and outside the container

Comment: Absolutely right of you. I was logging in debug mode and it just was freezing in the middle of reading ZipInputStream. The reason was a "silent" crash of thread - none of my vague suggestions. So it was just hard to debug. Excuse my "Enterprise".